# file() fails to read each line in txt file into new array element

Tags: php, file

I'm using `php` to read a file with a bunch of words in it, each line contains a single word.

I've seen this same question asked before but I'm using this:

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
```

When doing a `print_r($lines)` on the array it shows an array with a single element containing the entire file in that single element `[0]`.

Is there another way of getting each line in the text file into a new array element?

For reference, the file was simply a dictionary of sorts, which looked like this:

```
Downwards
Draw
Dream
Dress
Drink
Drive
Drop
```

Comment: `$lines = explode('\n',$lines);`

Comment: This should work, unless there is a permission issue. Try debugging by using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @SamBattat - I'm not seeing any errors. I got it to work using 

 '$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt');'
 '$lines = preg_split('/\s+/', $lines);'

I'm not sure why file() didn't work.

Comment: @Lex BTW: You can write your own answer and accept it! So for the next person with the same problem will find the answer faster! (Can you post the first few lines of the file how it looked like?)

Comment: `file()` didn't worked because it's all on one line!

Comment: What type of line endings does the file use?

Comment: @Rizier123 - sorry, edited. They're all on different lines

Comment: Try doing `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);` before calling `file()`

Comment: @prodigitalson do you mean \n \r \t etc? It's a txt file

Comment: @Lex: yes thats exactly what i mean... By default PHP assumed `\n` but it could be something else depending on the system and application that created the file.

Comment: @prodigitalson that seems to have worked! Perhaps I should recreate the file on my machine. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file probably uses line endings other than `\n`. Turn on auto detection first:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$lines = file('file.txt');
print_r($lines);
```

If desired, and you have access you can also set this in the `php.ini`.